# Убрать пробелы в url

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Ссылка на пост формируется из указанного пользователем заголовка. Например заголовок "Привет мир" выдасть url /post/privet-mir , но если написать "При  вет"
(после "при" два пробела), тогда ссылка будет /post/pri%C2%A0-vet и конечно же эта ссылка битая и пост не отображается.

Метод который сохраняет пост:

```
editor.save().then((outputData) => {
                    let postParams = {};
                    //postParams.name = $("#name").text();
                    postParams.name = $.trim($("#name").text())
                    postParams.add = $("#add").val();
                    postParams.access_id = $("#access_id").val();
                    postParams.price = $("#price").val();
                    postParams.tag = $("#tag").val();
                    postParams.group_id = $("#group_id").val();
                    postParams.repost_id = <?php echo $_GET['repost_id'] ? $_GET['repost_id'] : 0; ?>;
                    postParams.content = outputData;

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: '/post/add',
                        data: postParams,
                        success: function (data) {
                            // window.location.replace("/post/" + data);
                            // window.location.replace("/post/" + encodeURIComponent(data));
                            window.location.replace(encodeURI("/post/" + data));

                        }
                    });
                });
```

Поле что нам необходимо это поле name, как видно я делаю для него $.trim, но логично что он убирает двойные пробелы только в начале и конце ссылки.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Правильно понимаю что вам нужно любое количество пробелов заменить на `-` ? Если да, то примените к своему `url` `replace` с регулярным выражением

```
YOURURL.replace(/ /g, '-')
```

Answer (score 0):

Можете воспользоваться методом `str.replace`:

```js
$("#name").text().replace(/\s/g, '');
```